# The exact definition of max(,)?

Tags: definition, maxima-minima

So I'm a bit confused with the notation of $\max_x f(x,y)$.

I am aware that it is a function of $y$, and how to calculate it is to set $y$ to a certain value and find the value of $x$ where the $f(x,y)$ is at maxima. (If I am wrong please correct me.)

However, does this $\max_x f(x,y)$ refers a function itself or just a single point??

In terms of function, I mean as in $g(y) = \max_x f(x,y)$

Or does it mean that in the end, out of all those $x$ values that I get for each $y$, I have to pick "only one" where it represents the point where the function is at the maxima.

I'm trying to understand this equation: $$\max_{a,b} f(a)g(a,b) = \max_a [f(a) \max_b g(a,b)] .$$ But I dont know what the equation represents.

Comment: [Welcome to Math.SE!](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4928/290189) Please use MathJax.  For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [basic help on MathJax notation](/help/notation), [MathJax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/290189), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/259305) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773/290189).

Comment: Sorry and sure! I will do so.

Comment: I'm assuming $a$ and $b$ are numbers here. $\max$ in this context would be a value, i.e., in that equation you have a product of $f$ and $g$, and you want to find the pair of numbers $(a, b)$ which maximizes such product. The right hand side tells you that such maximum value for the product can be found by treating the product as a function of $a$, and finding the $b$ which maxes it; then, by maximizing for $a$, you get the pair you were seeking initially. So yeah, $\max_x f(x,y)$ is a function of $y$ in this case.

Comment: Your explanation clarifies a lot. Thank you so much!